# How to execute junit Rules inside AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests transaction?

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I want to do some database operations INSIDE the test method transaction. I would like to use junit TestRules for this. But the rules are executed outside of the transaction. Is there any way to have my rules executed inside the transaction?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
public class ProductServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

public @Rule @Autowired MySimpleSpringRule mySimpleSpringRule;

@Before
public void before() {
    logger.debug("before");
}

@After
public void after() {
    logger.debug("after");
}

@Test
public void testFindProducts() {
...
```

and

```
@Component
public class MySimpleSpringRule implements TestRule {

private class Banaani extends ExternalResource {
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
        logger.debug("before");
    };

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        logger.debug("after");
    };
}

private final Banaani banaani = new Banaani();

@Override
public Statement apply(Statement st, Description desc) {
    return banaani.apply(st, desc);
}
```

results in

```
2013-01-18 10:33:24,845 DEBUG [main]: MySimpleSpringRule         - before
2013-01-18 10:33:24,869 INFO  [main]: ionalTestExecutionListener - Began transaction (1): transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@a713a5]; rollback [true]
2013-01-18 10:33:24,869 DEBUG [main]: ProductServiceTest         - before
2013-01-18 10:33:24,869 DEBUG [main]: ProductServiceTest         - running test...
2013-01-18 10:33:24,984 DEBUG [main]: ProductServiceTest         - after
2013-01-18 10:33:24,986 INFO  [main]: ionalTestExecutionListener - Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [[TestContext@67946a testClass = ProductServiceTest, testInstance = fi.liikennevirasto.service.ProductServiceTest@40f0b2, testMethod = testFindRootProducts@ProductServiceTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@17a6b96 testClass = ProductServiceTest, locations = '{classpath:/META-INF/spring/test-bean-configuration.xml, classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml, classpath:/META-INF/spring/infrastructure.xml}', classes = '{}', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader']]]
2013-01-18 10:33:24,987 DEBUG [main]: MySimpleSpringRule         - after
```

The @Before and @After methods directly in test class are executed inside the transaction, but the ones in MySimpleSpringRule are executed outside the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be possible using @Rules....?

If not, same thing could be done using http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/TestExecutionListener.html